# Automating embed content in Internet Explorer using Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

[Table I am trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF3pl.png)
I am trying to access a table on a webpage that lies in an embed tag. I'm unable to access (I need to check/uncheck the checkboxes) the table using Internet Explorer. The code works fine in Firefox and Chrome.
The HTML content is as below

My problem is that in IE I can't find any contents of the table even with page source or inspect element, so I can't do anything with my table.

Comment: in firefox i can access the table by switching to that frame driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: in internet explorer there is no frame.it resides as an embed content

Comment: i am doing automation with selenium